# How can I make Sticky Header in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I have a page that desinged like that,

```
Grid->Textblock + Button
Grid->Textblock + Button
Grid->Textblock + Button
Grid->Textblock + Button
Pivot ->Pivot Item + Pivot Item -> ListBox
```

so these items aren't fit into my page and I decided add scrollviewer as a parent. There is a problem that the last item, Listbox, should be fit into page before scrolling scrollviewer and after scrolling scrollviewer, listbox's height will be increased and fill the page.

[image: Before Scrolling]

[image: After Scrolling]

[image: Description]

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand, what you mean. Can you describe (or paint) what you want to archive? It sounds like you want to increase the size of a listbox after scrolling into it? Sounds strange :)

Answer (score 0):

You could react on the `ManipulationStarted` Event of the `ScrollViewer` and set the `Visibility` of all elements above the pivot to `Collapsed` there.

Preferably you should do that with an animation to offer a nicer usability.

This could llok like this:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="YourGridWithOtherStuff" />

<ScrollViewer ManipulationStarted="OnScrollChangedEventHander">
    <!-- Rest of your code -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void OnScrollChangedEventHander(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    if (YourGridWithOtherStuff.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        // AnimationFade.Begin();
        YourGridWithOtherStuff.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I shouldn't collapse my elements :(